# how to show same labels as bar chart on inverted column chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to achieve same as in this picture.

[image]

I found  that only way to do it is column chart inverted, problem is label lines disappear. And if i hide gridlines, 0 yaxis line doesnt disapear.

Is it possible to just hide upper grid lines using zones, or hide them all together and redraw lines manually

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
```

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/warnisw/0qbdyf92/76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `gridLines` you can use properly styled ticks:

```
yAxis: [{
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    tickLength: 10,
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#FFF',
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2g1a8nx3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickWidth